# Exception thrown while logging in to project in windows 7 but fine with XP

Tags: java, windows, ms-access

I'm a final year student learning and trying to build a Java project and I've got a project in Java and MSAccess (jdbc). Th project is basically done but only executing fine under windows XP & jdk1.5. But I use windows7 64bit OS and installed jdk1.7. But I'm not able to login to the project. I've done those odbc - system dsn creation procedure both by *.mdb in Access02-03 & in *.mdb,*.accdb. but having the same Exception "unable to connect to the database". The login gui is taking the value of UserName and password, but as I press the login button it's throwing the exception. It is created in netbeans, though I have the latest version of netbeans installed in my system.It is throwing the same Exception from the commandline as well from netbeans. I have checked all those codings, dsn name, tablenames, ield names, but we all know that Java is a completely platform independent language. So I think there won't be any issues with the version of OS or JDK installed on the system.

Comment: Some sample code and the stacktrace would be helpful here.

Comment: What Exception is being thrown?

Comment: If you paste exception trace that could really get you answers fast.